# Matching id reference between two tables and exclude result with connection user id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - simplified they look like this:

```
//TABLE A
player_img_id || player_img_category_id

//TABLE B
user_play_uid || user_play_img_id (reference to TABLE A: player_img_id)
```

How do I show all results from **TABLE A** where I exclude rows based on reference entries from **TABLE B** WHERE result_should_exclude_reference_with for instance `user_play_uid = 1` AND `user_play_img_id == player_img_id`.

Basically I want to show results from TABLE A that I dont have any referenced user entry for in TABLE B.
Note: that to start of with, there will be no user entries in **TABLE B**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, read a basic tutorial about joins or post what you've tried. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the JOINS - just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment I found my solution by reading a bit on JOINS here:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

The query I needed was the following:

```
SELECT * FROM player_img
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_play
  ON user_play.user_play_entry_player_img_id = player_img.player_img_id
  AND user_play.user_play_uid != $this->user_uid
  WHERE user_play.user_play_entry_player_img_id IS null
```